# "CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version" - but it isn't

Tags: cuda

I have CUDA 10.1 installed on my Linux system under under `/usr/local/cuda-10.1` (and linked to from `/usr/local/cuda`). After some package updates and removals (which I can go into if you like), I also have the NVIDIA drivers, version  440.82, installed (nvidia-smi says as much).

However, when I build and run this minimal program:

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    int deviceCount;
    cudaError_t error_id = cudaGetDeviceCount(&deviceCount);
    if (error_id != cudaSuccess) {
        printf("cudaGetDeviceCount returned %d: %s\n", (int)error_id, cudaGetErrorString(error_id));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

using the command:

```
 g++ -o min -I/usr/local/cuda/include  min.cpp -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64  -lcudart
```

I get:

```
cudaGetDeviceCount returned 35: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
```

How is this possible, and what can I do about it?

Comment: Two things -- libraries always *after* source and objects, and add `-v` and add the output to your question. And ldd output on the executable. Also I don't see how that would compile without -I for the CUDA include paths or -L for the linker paths

Comment: @talonmies: `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`, `LIBRARY_PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: If you are using environment variables, it would be helpful to know that you set them

Comment: broken driver install is the only idea I have.  `nvidia-smi` isn't a perfect test for a properly installed driver.  If you have old driver components floating around, perhaps due to a mix of driver install procedures, then you might get this report.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: This may have been it. But - what is a better test for the driver version, then?

Comment: You just ran a pretty good test.  The CUDA installation guides generally recommend this sort of verification of a successful install.  See [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#verify-installation)

Comment: @RobertCrovella: But they don't really tell you what exactly it is that they found... but thanks for the link.

Comment: That's correct.  Testing at this level is pretty much binary: "its working" vs. "its not working".  Since this is a driver issue ("cuda driver version is insufficient for cuda runtime version..."), the usual advice is just to clean out and reinstall the driver, rather than try and do some surgical updating.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: And is `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version` a sufficient test?

Comment: clearly not.  That is reading a file, right?  I probably won't respond to additional questions in this vein.  I've already told you what I know about what is a sufficient test, including documentational support.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: No, it's not a real file. `/proc` is a filesytem-like interface to information and settings in the Linux kernel. Also - I quoted from the test in the documentation link you gave me...

Comment: That's correct, it's one step in the verification process.  It is not the complete process.  Therefore suggesting it is "sufficent" wouldn't be sensible.  The complete process is outlined in section 7.2.3, to include the **entire** section.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: What I'm looking a way to determine _whether_ those examples would work, not run them and check :-)

Comment: But you're willing to run a compiled executable, namely `nvidia-smi`, provided by NVIDIA?  If so, provide a compiled executable, like the one you have described in this question, or like what is described in the doc section I linked.  I don't have any other suggestions.  The recommended method is as I indicated.  I don't have any other recommendations or suggestions.  You're welcome to file bugs at developer.nvidia.com indicating your needs.

Answer (score 1):

#### The nVIDIA driver is mis-installed somehow

As @RobertCrovella suggests, it seems I had some apt packages still installed relating to an older driver version - despite what `nvidia-smi` was telling me. Specifically, `nvidia-kernel-dkms` was an older version.

Look for the version numbers on the packages you get with `sudo dpkg -l "nvidia-*"` (and which are installed).

I was not, however, able to figure out exactly what I needed to add/update in order to get my simple program to run. Eventually I caved and went for a manual driver installation.

Comment: I have the exact same problem as you. I uninstalled all nvidia drivers by `sudo apt remove nvidia-*` and reinstalled my 470 driver from ppa `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. However error persists. Can you please describe the steps for your "manual driver installation"?

Comment: I mean I installed the .run file from Nvidia but after reboot, `nvidia-smi` doesn't work..

Comment: @Panos: Uninstalled distribution packages, downloaded an executable (not distro package) from NVIDIA's site for the driver.

Comment: That's what I did using the driver directly from NVIDIA, but it didn't work either. Even worse, it somehow broke my driver installation and I couldn't get my 2nd monitor displaying even after reinstalling nvidia-driver-470 from the distro package.

Comment: @Panos: I'm sorry :-( ... maybe you can ask on the NVIDIA forums, sometimes you can have better luck finding answers there than here.